# Getting Strange message when creating a browser instance

Tags: jxbrowser

I am using JxBrowser (6.23.1) on windows 10 and using the 64-bit library. however, when i startup the demo application I get the following Log message.

> SEVERE: [0528/084716.632:ERROR:browser_process_stub.cpp(279)] NOT IMPLEMENTED

Can anyone shed light on this and whether this is an issue?

I have tried to find anything in relation to above error code, but did not find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `browser_process_stub.cpp(279)] NOT IMPLEMENTED` message means that Chromium engine tries to get access to the specific code of JxBrowser which is not implemented at the moment due to the fact that this functionality is not supported by JxBrowser at the moment. This method does not affect the existing JxBrowser functionality, so you can safely ignore this error message.

Comment: OK, thank you for the information, though it is strange that on different machines both running Win10 64 on one i do get this error-log, and on the other machine i don't...